# Sync result of SQL Server view and table MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have a table with many columns in SQL Server and I have move part of data into MySQL. I made a view or function on the table in SQL Server and these two databases must be synced once a day through job. Because the data of this view may change every day.

View return a table with 3 columns: (`char`, `varchar`, `varchar`) that none of them are unique or primary key.

My solution is:

1. create a job
2. execute view on SQL Server
3. return result of view
4. create temp table with 3 column in MySQL
5. move result view from SQL Server to temp table
6. move records from temp table to new table one by one if not exist before
7. delete temp table

To transfer without using the temp table, I wanted to use below type of query but could not find the correct query. That's why I used the temp table:

```
insert into new_table
    values (array of records) where record if not exist in new table.
```

And for the solution I mentioned above, I used the following query:

```
insert into new_table
    select *
    from temp_table
    where not exist new_table.column = temp_table.column
```

Do you have a better suggestion that new records can be fetch and added to previous records?

Answer (score 2):

It should look more like this:

```
insert into new_table
    select *
    from temp_table
    where not exists (
        select 1 
        from new_table
        where new_table.column = temp_table.column            
    )
```

or maybe this:

```
insert into new_table
    select *
    from temp_table
    where not exists (
        select 1 
        from new_table
        where new_table.column = temp_table.column
            and new_table.column2 = temp_table.column2
            and new_table.column3 = temp_table.column3         
    )
```

Comment: Do you know a better way than making a middle table? In my opinion, the best way is to read the added records from the source table and move them to the destination table directly.

Comment: It is possible to do that, but staging tables are common anyway. They help with performance by allowing the database to make better estimates and ram and page grants, since everything for the final insert is in the same DB, they help avoid disruption to the live target table, and they make it easier to match up records so you can merge or skip records that already exist.